# query is throttled by bandwidth cosmos db

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am creating a report in power bi desktop that is connected to a cosmos db of azure, I have a problem and it is that the documents are load intermittently when I am refreshing the data of the report, the data is not loaded to more than 35 Mbps and this does it intermittently; additionally already verify the number of RUs assigned to the database and they are more than enough to extract the data from the database, It doesn't even matter what number of RUs I assign to the database, the performance is always the same and does not improve in any case(2000 RUs,5000 RUs,10000 RUs, 20000 RUs, etc..). Also check the application server bandwidth to verify that it was not a network issue, but the bandwidth is sufficient to load more documents during loading, the limit reached is only 35 Mbps. The number of documents to extract is approximately 1,750,000 which is the total number of documents in the database.The query I am asking is the following:

```
select * from c
```

These are screenshots of the execution metrics of a query with 50,000 documents
[image]
[image]

The problem has nothing to do with RUs, in fact there is no request with HTTP code 429, so my question is:

What can cause the bandwidth limit when recovering data from the database to my application server?

Comment: Hi Andres - you asked this exact same question yesterday (which has already been closed as off-topic) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59957389/traffic-limit-in-cosmos-db. With no changes to the question, this will likely be closed again. Much better to update your original question to be more specific. Please don't re-post closed questions.

Comment: Hi @DavidMakogon

There are changes in the original question, you have not bothered to read it all again and you are closing the question, in fact I made changes to the original question and they did not reopen the question so I published it again.